# excel shortcut for month day year short date

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

The following excel shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+#) formats dates as dd-mm-yy (with month abbreviated).

Is there a way to change the format for the shortcut to m/d/yyyy?

so for the date August 6, 20016

currently CTRL+SHIFT+# =>  6-Aug-16, but how can I get CTRL+SHIFT+# => 8/6/2016?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Questions about general software use belong on [su] instead.

Comment: Ok. Did not realize will use super user next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `Ctrl-1 + Tab + Tab + Tab + Up` 
(If Ctrl-1 starts you in the Custom Category)

In my Excel 2010:

1. Select both cells 05-Aug-16 , 06-Aug-16
2. Ctrl-1 + Tab + Tab + Tab + UpArrow
3. 05/08/2016 , 06/08/2016

Takes about 1s